# How To Add Aspx page to aspx page with url?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have 2 .Net projects. ProjX, ProjY. They are located different directories. PageA in ProjX and PageB in ProjY. So, I want to include PageA to PageB. I used

`var control =  Page.LoadControl("http://localhost/ProjX/PageA.aspx");
Page.Controls.Add(control);`

But I get `'http://localhost/ProjX/PageA.aspx' is not a valid virtual path.` error.

Is it possible to include an external aspx page to another aspx page via url or directory? I used iframe but I want to use page controls and iframe doesn't let this.

Comment: 'http://localhost/ProjA/PageA.aspx' - ProjA is aspx page right ? Try changing to ProjX.

Comment: I wrote wrong, should be localhost/ProjX/PageA.aspx. Of course, they're not real project and page names.  @ADarnal

Comment: I think,there is no way to add one aspx page into another other than using iframe.You can use UserControls (ascx) instead.

Comment: I tried with ascx but it doesn't work. It looks that there is no way without using iframe. Thanks for your answer @ADarnal .